# How can i use Window Tree Node in C#.net with Proper Windows Directory having path hard coded?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am building an application in C#.net .net framework 4 and i have a treenode in it having file system, i have used its current controls but they dont have icons and they are not like professional windows directory based tree node, please help if you know some dll or control which can help in it, the tree node should also have icons with proper path with a panel. For example, there is a folder and has file in pdf format. Then it should auto pick the pdf icon for that file, if it is folder, it should have folder icon, i think i should attach the image, what i am exactly finding. 
[image]

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28VS.85%29.aspx), passing the `SHGFI_SMALLICON` flag. You'll need to use P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) containing all the icons you need and assign it to the TreeView (.ImageList property). You can then pick the appropriate icon from the list for each node. If you need to assign the icon dynamically (e.g based on whether a folder contains any files or not) then you will need to do this in code at run time rather than at design time.

You can use the standard Windows icons or there are any number of free icon sites to go to, [here](http://www.iconarchive.com/) for example.

Comment: I want, it should auto pick the icon, we cannot assign 1000s of extensions icon as you know. Please help.